# Heap corruption when using realloc - VS 2010

Tags: realloc

so my prgrm works fine until i tried to realloc a pointer, but it doesn't crash all the time. sometimes it does, sometimes it runs just fine. anyone please tells me what's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

char getword(char[]); //return length

int main()
{   

    static char buffer[100];
    int wcount = 5, n = 0;
    char **p = (char**) malloc (wcount);
    int len = getword(buffer);
    while (len && n < wcount)
    {
        p[n] = (char *) malloc (len);
        strncpy(p[n++], buffer, len);
        len = getword(buffer);
        if (n == wcount)
        {
            wcount += 10;
            char** temp = (char**) realloc (p, wcount);
            if (temp == NULL)
                break;
            else
                p = temp;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

char getword(char buffer[])
{
    int len = 0;
    char c = getchar();

    if (c == EOF)
        return len;

    while (c == 32 || c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == '\v')
    {
        c = getchar();
    }
    do
    {
        buffer[len++] = c;
        c = getchar();
    }
    while (c != 32 && c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c != '\v' && c != EOF);
    buffer[len] = 0;
    return ++len;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char **p = (char**) malloc (wcount);` allocates `wcount` bytes, not `wcount` pointers. Similarly `realloc`.

Comment: ooooh i see. i see. so would this work:

Comment: char **p = (char * *) malloc (wcount * sizeof(char * ));

Comment: Thank you so much Raymond! it works!! ^^!!!

Comment: Wow, thanks! It's always those little things that take the most time to find!